# CodeIgniter routes problem with controller's index function

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-url

My current development is using CodeIgniter, and when I try to pass some parameters to index function of my main controller it returns me `404 error`.

```
http://localhost/gis/1 -> 404 ERROR
http://localhost/gis/home/1 -> 404 ERROR
```

Actually my `route.php` file has a route like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";    

$route['home/([:num])'] = 'home/index/$1';
```

My `.htaccess` file is this (from [this post](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/) to take away index.php from CI urls):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And my `config.php` file:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/gis";

$config['index_page'] = "";
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What is your default controller in `routes.php` ?

Comment: @Sarfraz I edit my own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

**Quoting OP:**

> .htaccess wasn't guilty. The problem
>   was that my route needs to be
>   $route['home/(:num)'] = ... I added
>   both parenthesis and all works.

---

Rather than:

```
$route['home/([:num])'] = 'home/index/$1';
```

Try specifying it like this:

```
$route['home/:num'] = 'home/index/$1';
```

Also make sure that from `application/config/routes.php`, your default controller is set to `home`:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I tried what you said but it didn't work for me. If I try to print the parameter in my main controller index function, always print '$1'. Can you help me?

Comment: @Fran Verona: Try disabling the .htaccess file to check if there is something wrong in it.

Comment: htaccess wasn't guilty. The problem was that my route needs to be $route['home/(:num)'] = ... I added both parenthesis and all works. Can you edit your own answer to add this? Thank you so much Sarfraz.

Comment: @Fran: Glad to know it works, I think you were already using parentheses as in your question. I will update the answer though :)